# GO DB Pool size

Tags: go, psql, pq

consider the following Scenario

DB pool settings are:

```
func NewDB(Log *zap.SugaredLogger) *DBClient {
    dbname := viper.GetString("DB_NAME")
    user := viper.GetString("DB_USER")
    password := viper.GetString("DB_PASSWORD")
    host := viper.GetString("DB_HOST")
    port := viper.GetInt("DB_PORT")

    dbInfo := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%v:%v@%v:%v/%v?sslmode=disable",
        user, password, host, port, dbname)
    Log.Infof("Connection String: %v", dbInfo)
    dbConn, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbInfo)
    if err != nil {
        err := fmt.Errorf("db_error: %v", err)
        Log.Error(err)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = dbConn.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        err := fmt.Errorf("db_error: %v", err)
        Log.Error(err)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    dbConn.SetMaxIdleConns(viper.GetInt("DB_MIN_POOL")) // Maximum idle connections
    dbConn.SetMaxOpenConns(viper.GetInt("DB_MAX_POOL")) // Maximum open connections
    dbConn.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Duration(viper.GetInt("DB_CONN_TIME")) * time.Minute)

    Log.Info("Postgres connected.")
    DB = dbConn

    return &DBClient{Log: Log, DB: dbConn}
}
```

```
sql.DBStats{MaxOpenConnections:250, OpenConnections:250, InUse:250, Idle:0, WaitCount:399, WaitDuration:4442935235, MaxIdleClosed:0, MaxIdleTimeClosed:0, MaxLifetimeClosed:69}
```

MY DB pool size is not coming down.Post this we have increased the size to 2000 and we are restarting our service once in a day.

DB Stat : `sql.DBStats{MaxOpenConnections:2000, OpenConnections:154, InUse:151, Idle:3, WaitCount:0, WaitDuration:0, MaxIdleClosed:0, MaxIdleTimeClosed:0, MaxLifetimeClosed:258}`

Didn't do much we have increased pool size to 2000 and we are restarting our service once in a day.

How can we solve this problem?
I want to bring my pool size down and close all idle connections

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you keeping idle connections open?
   [SetMaxIdleConns](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetMaxIdleConns) will help you to kill out idle connections. Setting this value to `-1` does the required.

If there is no particular reason, you can kill off idle connections.

Comment: i have set so that they can be reused

Comment: Looking at your data itself, make a good guess on the threshold as to how many average number of min connections you require. There is not much point in keeping so many connections open. You are just hogging system resources that way. If you reduce your min idle connections, you can keep your max open connections low too (Make a guess what that would be the case). Given you want to `close all idle connections` as you have mentioned, this should solve your problem.

Comment: @PujithReddy , Please accept the answer if you found it helpful!